# How can I attach to a ConEmu tab via SSH?

Tags: windows, ssh, console, conemu

I would like to be able to start long-running processes on my Windows machine (for example, video transcoding) via SSH, then disconnect and leave the process running, then reattach to the session later.

I know that something *kind of* like this is possible by using GNU Screen through Cygwin, but I'd much prefer the ability to opt for cmd.exe, cygwin or PowerShell as needed.

Ideally, I'd be able to interact with the console locally as well, if I'm at the machine. Is there some way that I can start a persistent console which can both be accessed from the local machine, and can be attached to from an SSH session?

Comment: you can access `screen` or `tmux` both remotely and locally.

Comment: I'm having problems getting `screen` to reattach to a shell, even when said shell was started through the same SSH session. I'm in the process of writing up my findings.